# java rabbitmq acknowledgment invalid

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I use the java language to test the connection to RabbitMQ, two consumers, one of the consumers, got the message, but did not successfully consume, I want to try RabbitMQ to send this failed message to another consumer.

View official documentation [enter link description here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html)，provide **Message acknowledgment**

And run the example, but did not achieve the expected results

code show as below：

- worker1

```java
package com.gp.rabbitmq;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.DeliverCallback;

/**
 * @author gao peng
 * @date 2019/11/15 15:08
 */
public class WorkerDemo {

  private static final String TASK_QUEUE_NAME = "task_queue";

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(GPHost.ip);
    final Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    final Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

//    channel.basicQos(1);

    DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
      String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");

      System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
      try {
        doWork(message);
      } finally {
//        System.out.println(" [x] Done");
//        channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
      }
    };
    channel.basicConsume(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, false, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> {});
  }

  private static void doWork(String task) {
    for (char ch : task.toCharArray()) {
      if (ch == '.') {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException _ignored) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- worker2

```java
package com.gp.rabbitmq;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.DeliverCallback;

/**
 * @author gao peng
 * @date 2019/11/15 15:08
 */
public class WorkerDemo2 {

  private static final String TASK_QUEUE_NAME = "task_queue";

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(GPHost.ip);
    final Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    final Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

//    channel.basicQos(1);

    DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
      String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");

      System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
      try {
        doWork(message);
      } finally {
        System.out.println(" [x] Done");
        channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
      }
    };
    channel.basicConsume(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, false, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> {});
  }

  private static void doWork(String task) {
    for (char ch : task.toCharArray()) {
      if (ch == '.') {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException _ignored) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- sender

```
package com.gp.rabbitmq;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

/**
 * @author gao peng
 * @date 2019/11/15 14:49
 */
public class SendingDemo {

  private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "task_queue";

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("192.168.9.214");

    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);

    String message = "Hello World BEijing!1";
    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    String message1 = "Hello World BEijing!2";
    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    String message2 = "Hello World BEijing!3";
    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message2.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    channel.close();
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

Output result：

- worker1

```
 [x] Received 'Hello World BEijing!2'
```

- worker2

```
 [x] Received 'Hello World BEijing!1'
 [x] Done
 [x] Received 'Hello World BEijing!3'
 [x] Done
```

worker1 No successful return`channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);` However, RabbitMQ does not send messages to the other workers.

Comment: What is meant by "does not send messages to the other workers?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of what is going on aligns perfectly with your code. Somewhere, you're getting tripped up by the documentation.

Some facts:

1. RabbitMQ distributes messages from queues to consumers in a round-robin fashion.
2. RabbitMQ has no notion of "sending a message to a consumer." Messages are *published* with a routing key, then *routed* to one or more queues depending upon *bindings*. Once a message hits a queue, it may be *consumed* by exactly one consumer.
3. Worker 1 requires messages to be acknowledged by the `basic.consume` call. However, the portion of the code where the message is actually acknowledged is commented out. Thus, Worker 1 only receives one message, and the message is not re-delivered until (a) worker 1 is disconnected or (b) a [`basic.nack`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html) is sent.
4. Worker 2 also requires acknowledgements, but the code to do that has been left in. Thus the output shows Worker 2 finishing the first, getting the third, and finishing that as well.

Comment: There is no problem, my example above can achieve the desired results. It should be my running. Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: [https://github.com/rabbitmq/discussions/issues/9](https://github.com/rabbitmq/discussions/issues/9)